# lottery loop through random numbers in a list find how many counts it took to find it

Tags: python, python-3.x

im very new to python and cant figure out a basic matching game using lottery numbers.

i have 6 numbers. the first 5 numbers are between 1-49 and the last number is 1-7.
i cant seem to loop through where after it checks it, it generates another random number.

edited:

how do i remove duplicates from range(0,4)?

```
import random

def lottery(ticket):
    count = 0
    run = True
    while count < 200:
        lottoNum = sorted([random.randint(1,49) for x in range(5)])
        lottoNum.append(random.randint(1,7))

        if lottoNum != ticket:
            count += 1
            print(lottoNum)

        else:
            run = False
            print(lottoNum, count)

lottery([11, 12, 36, 39, 46, 1])
```

Comment: In the while loop none of `lottoNum` and `ticket` changes, so this loop will run 0 or 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `lottoNum` definition inside the while loop in order to update it every loop, like this:

```
import random

def lottery(ticket):
    count = 0
    while count < 1000:
        lottoNum = [random.randint(1, 49) for x in range(6)]
        lottoNum[-1] = random.randint(1, 7)
        if lottoNum !=  ticket:
            count += 1
            print(lottoNum)

print(lottery([11, 12, 36, 39, 46, 1]))
```

With this correction, you allow 1000 attempts to the `lottery` function to guess the correct input, stored in `ticket`.
Moreover, you `lottery` function does not have a `return` statement (it returns nothing), so, in Python, such a function returns a value `None`. This is the reason why there is no point in printing the 'result' of the function in the line `print(lottery([11, 12, 36, 39, 46, 1]))`: this `print` statement will print always `None` because your function `lottery` does not returns anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random


def lottery(ticket):
    """
    Compare lottery ticket against lottery draws and print how many draws have taken place
    to match the ticket.
    """

    count = 0
    run = True

    while run:
        lotto_num = [random.randint(1, 49) for _ in range(6)]
        lotto_num[-1] = random.randint(1, 7)

        if lotto_num != ticket:
            print(f"No match! Your ticket {ticket}, Lottery ticket {lotto_num}")
            count += 1
        else:
            print(f"Match! Your ticket {ticket} lottery ticket {lotto_num}")
            print(f"{count} draws")
            run = False


lottery([11, 12, 36, 39, 46, 1])
```

Comment: i like this. is there a way to simplify the code? how do i short hand it? when it searchings, it searching for the exact numbers in those exact order. is there a way to match it in any order or do i need to sort it first? because the last number is between 1-7, how could i sort just the first 5 numbers?